# consequences of calling a function with fewer arguments in C?

Tags: c, function, arguments, call

I wrote a function that that takes some argument and a pointer argument . when calling the function , sometimes I need to pass along the pointer for use inside the function and sometimes I don't .
what are the consequences of calling a function with fewer arguments ? it compiles correctly and during runtime its still fine , but is this good programming ? is it better if I call the function with a dummy variable ?
Thanks and sorry for beginner question .

Comment: Is passing NULL into the 'unused parameter' not an option?

Comment: It's certainly not *good programming*. Even if it compiles, it must throw warnings. The function call must match its prototype which must match its definition signature.

Comment: turn on warnings, all of them. furiously heed them.

Comment: If your function expects three arguments and you call it with two, you invoke undefined behaviour, which is to be avoided at all costs because the compiler can make your program do anything when you invoke undefined behaviour.  Don't risk it; pass the full complement of arguments, always, even if they're NULL.  And if it compiles correctly, you are not making correct use of C or your compiler.

Comment: @user3668489 : can you paste the code into your question, so everybody can stop guessing and see exactly what is going on?

Answer (score 5):

If you call a function with too few arguments and the compiler doesn't complain, then you're doing something wrong.

You *can* write a function declaration/definition that doesn't specify how many arguments it requires:

```
void func();
/* ... */
func();
func(arg1);
func(arg1, arg2);
```

All three of those calls will be accepted by the compiler, but at least two of them are incorrect.

That form of function declaration/definition has been *obsolescent* since the 1989 ANSI C standard.

Never use this form.

Functions declaration should *always* be written as *prototypes*, i.e., declarations that specify the number and type(s) of the parameters. As a special case, `(void)` denotes a function with no parameters.

```
void func(int arg);
/* ... */
func();           /* rejected by compiler */
func(arg1);       /* accepted -- but only if arg1 is of type int or convertible to int */
func(arg1, arg2); /* rejected by compiler */
```

If you manage to write code that calls a function with an incorrect number of arguments and get it past the compiler, the behavior is undefined. It might appear to "work", but it could blow up in your face when, for example, you compile it with a different compiler, or with the same compiler and different options.

One complication: some functions are *variadic*, taking a variable number of arguments. The most common example of this is `printf`. For variadic functions, the required arguments are typically specified by the function's documentation -- and it's just as important to get the arguments right. The difference is that, for variadic functions, your compiler won't necessarily tell you that a call is incorrect.

The `, ...` syntax (in the function declaration) and the macros defined in `<stdarg.h>` are the *only* legitimate way to write and use C functions that take a variable number and type(s) of arguments.

Comment: "The compiler doesn't complain" - do you mean show a warning at compile time, or an error? I only got a warning (accidentally called with one too many arguments), does that mean that my prototype in the .h file is not visible?

Comment: @RoG: The C standard only requires a "diagnostic message" for a violation of a syntax rule or constraint. A non-fatal warning suffices, and many C compilers print warnings for many violations. Take warnings seriously.

Answer (score 1):

One of the differences of C++ over plain C is that it incorporates *name mangling*, which lets you specify a single function with varying return types and parameters. Two functions that share the same name but have different parameters:

```
int foo();
int foo(int param1, char* param2);
```

can be done in C++ because it actually alters the name of functions behind-the scenes as it compiles it. When you want to pass in a different number of parameters, it's essentially the same as having two different function names that it calls:

```
int foo1();
int foo2(int param1, char* param2);
```

When you pass in fewer parameters than it expects, some compilers should at least throw warnings; others won't even compile the program at all.

Let's say that you pass in 2 parameters to a function that expects 3. When you try to reference that 3rd parameter within your function, what do you expect the value to be? Most of the time, it will be a garbage value, and definitely something your function does not expect.

I would suggest just passing in a dummy value to functions like that: a `NULL` for a pointer or a `0` or negative "uninitialized" kind of value for other types. You can at least test for those values in your function.  Or just write a second function that takes a different number of parameters.

Comment: if I pass a NULL pointer , does that have any consequences as well ? my program will work totally fine still .

Comment: Not if you check for `NULL` before trying to access the pointer, no. But it's usually safer to write it in a way that the pointer is either an expected value or `NULL`, giving no place for stray "garbage values" to leak into it and give you unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this.  I would only call the function with the declared number of arguments.

It is extremely confusing to the reader of the code.

The reader of the code might even think the function has been overloaded and look
for the other definitions of the function with fewer arguments.

The omitted arguments can have any value at all - anything is considered legal behavior by the C compiler.  The program may work perfectly in a test environment and then crash for any or no reason.

If I absolutely had to have a variable number of arguments, for a legitimate purpose, I would try to put the arguments in a list instead of using a variable number of arguments.  If someone else required me to use variable arguments, I would use varargs instead of the default behavior, and then only in the case where all the arguments are the same type.

Comment: `printf` takes a variable number of arguments, typically of different types. As long as a variadic function has enough information to know what to expect (in the case of `printf`, that information is in the format string), and as long as the calls are correct, there shouldn't be a problem. But the `, ...` syntax and `<stdarg.h>` are the *only* way to write and use C functions that accept a variable number and type(s) of arguments.

Comment: Yes, printf works; as far as I know there is no way for the compiler to detect whether or not the types passed into printf are valid at compile time - that is the risk I have always tried to avoid.