# Inconsistent declaration and definition in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings

Today I have spend considerable time finding a "bug" that can be demonstrated by this simple code:

**main.c**

```
#include "func.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){printf("func: %f", getX());}
```

**func.c**

```
#include "func.h"
static float x[2] = {1.0f, 2.0f};
float getX(int n){return x[n];}
```

**func.h**

```
float getX();
```

and it compiles & links (VS2010 with /W3) without **any warning**. 
Sample output from the run is

```
func: 1.000000
```

Can someone explain me how it can work if function declaration and definition do not match and why it is not worth to output any warning?

Thanks

Comment: `main` must return an `int` in [0,255], not `void`.  This is not your main bug, but it is a bug.

Comment: [**See this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c)

Comment: The key question of how the value of the argument gets set is not answered yet.

Comment: Why is it duplicate? The important part of the question was about passed argument i=0 to the function

Comment: Well there are two questions here really: why does this compile without warning/error, and why do I get an output of 1.0? Both questions are duplicates though - the first is a duplicate of the [the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929711/c-function-with-no-parameters-behavior) and the second is a duplicate of various questions such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833794/consequences-of-calling-a-function-with-fewer-arguments-in-c/23834194#23834194). Don't take it personally though - the question and its answers are still potentially useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C:

```
float getX();
```

is not the same as:

```
float getX(void);
```

In the first case you are specifying a function that returns `float` but takes *unspecified parameters* - in the second case you are specifying a function which returns `float` but which takes *no parameters*.

So a definition of the form `float getX(int n)` is compatible with the first case, but not the second, which explains why you do not seen an error/warning.

If you change to the correct prototype (the second version) then you should see the required error/warning.

Note that this is different behaviour than for C++, where the two forms are equivalent.

As for the output you are seeing when you run the program, this is just a random consequence of undefined behaviour - literally anything could happen if you call a function with incorrect parameters.

Take home message: in C you should always use the second form when declaring a prototype that takes no parameters - unfortunately you'll find that it's very common for people to omit the `void` (probably because of bad habits acquired from writing C++ code, or just because it requires fewer keystrokes).

Comment: Thanks, and from where the "default" argument "n=0" came to the function?

Comment: @Peter: it's not the "default" argument, it's undefined behavior.  It ended up being 1 on my machine.

Comment: That is just a random consequence of undefined behaviour - literally anything could happen if you call a function with incorrect parameters.

Comment: @PaulR Can you please add it to your answer for completeness? I will then accept it. Thanks a lot for explanation.

Comment: @Peter: sure - done already.

Answer (score 4):

This declaration means that getX accepts any number of parameters:

```
float getX();
```

To declare a function that takes no parameters, use:

```
float getX(void);  // This will result in a compiler error for func.c
```